# Unexpectedly receiving 'float too large for page' error while using a figure that is smaller than the page

Tags: floats, sharelatex, subfig

I am getting the following error while using `figure` and `subfigure` to create a 2 x 1 environment for my figures (i.e. one figure on top and two figures on the bottom) in an unexpected situation.

The document is generated successfully and my figures clearly fit on a single page and I can confirm this even visually, i.e. the page still has a lot of empty space left! But I still want to understand why this error is generated.

> Float too large for page by 14.86864pt on input line 58.

This is the block of code I am using:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,oneside,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[demo]{graphicx}
\usepackage{subcaption}

\begin{document}
\begin{figure}[htbp!]
  \centering
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{1\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{files/Feb1.pdf}
     \caption{No. 1 }
  \end{subfigure}
  \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{files/Feb2.pdf}
    \caption{No. 2 }
  \end{subfigure}
    \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.4\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{files/Feb3.pdf}
    \caption{No. 3 }
  \end{subfigure}
  \caption{\textit{40 characters here in the original version} 544 characters here}
  \label{fig:thesefiguresdonotmatter}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have already tried:

1. Remove `\centering`
2. Remove `[htbp!]` (in the first line)
3. Remove `[b]` (those next to `subfigure` commands)

Comment: with test of your code i can't confirm your findings. compilation not gives any warning nor bad boxes. please provide complete small document, which demonstrate your problem. welcome to tex.se!

Comment: i took liberty and complete your code snippet to compilable document. please test it and show us results. i'm convinced, that this code cannot produce what you claim. btw, figure position not influence on image size. please clarify what is your problem.

Comment: in editing i forgot to add package  `subcaption`. please add it yourself!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the float extends to the footer area, then the float is still too large.

The page layout can be made visible by option `showframe` of package `geometry`.
Add this option or if the package is not used add:

```
\usepackage[pass, showframe]{geometry}% pass does not change the layout
```

The macro `\DebugBox`, defined below, prints the dimensions to the console and the `.log` file and adds borders. The border lines are put inside the box to prevent that the box with border becomes larger.

```
\newcommand*{\DebugBox}[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \sbox0{#1}%
    \typeout{\string\DebugBox: wd=\the\wd0, ht=\the\ht0, dp=\the\dp0}%
    \setlength{\fboxrule}{.1pt}% thin border line
    \setlength{\fboxsep}{-\fboxrule}% border line inside
    \fbox{\box0}%
  \endgroup
}
```

Macro `\DebugBox` can be used like `\mbox`, example:

```
\DebugBox{\includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{files/Feb1.pdf}}
```